# How to insert a String as Integer to a List in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I need to insert a number (user input) as an integer to a Python list.

My code:

```
count = 0
list1 = []
for number in input():
    if number != ' ':
        list1.append(int(number))
```

Input: 10 11 12

Output: `[1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2]`

Expected Output: `[10, 11, 12]`

Comment: Please select any of the answers as [answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow) if you get your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looping over a string (such as the one returned by `input()`) will loop over the individual characters in the string:

```
>>> s = 'hi guys'
>>> for char in s:
...     print(char)
...
h
i

g
u
y
s
>>>
```

To loop over the "words" (i.e. substrings separated by spaces), you want to [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) the user's input instead:

```
>>> s = 'hi guys'
>>> words = s.split()
>>> words
['hi', 'guys']
>>> for word in words:
...     print(word)
...
hi
guys
>>>
```

So in your case, that would be:

```
for number in input().split():
    list1.append(int(number))
```

We can leave the `if number != ' ':` out because `split()` already gets rid of all the spaces and simply returns a list of the numbers.

Comment: @ÄyëShÑipün Make sure to [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) if it solved your problem :)

Answer (score -1):

You should use `split` method to split the values as a list with string:

```
str_nums = input.split() #will give ['10','11','12']
```

then

```
lst_nums = []
for i in str_nums.split():
  lst_nums.append(int(i))
print(lst_nums)
#output [10,11,12]
```

You can also use [map](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_lambda.php) and split together.

```
inp = "10 11 12"
print(list(map(int,inp.split(" "))))

#Output
[10,11,12]
```

Or

```
print([int(i) for i in input().split()])
```

Comment: This doesn't address the OP's issue. Surely you *can* use `list(map(int, s)))` instead of a `for` loop, but that's completely irrelevant to OP's issue, the `split()`. You can't use `list(map(int, s)))` if you do it like OP did, without `split()`

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen Sorry I didn't understand but how this does not solve the problem.

Comment: @Bhansa The code snippets you've shown *do* solve the problem, but not because of the `map()` and list comprehension, but simply because they call `str.split()`. Your answer doesn't even mention `split()`, but makes it sound like using `map()` or a comprehension is the way to fix his problem, when in reality they have nothing to do with it. "Use `split()`" is the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks @Markus, got it. My answer was more about to getting the output.

Answer (score -1):

Here You Go

```
input_array = []

c_input = input('please enter the input\n')

for item in c_input.split():

    input_array.append(int(item))

print (input_array)
```

input: - 1 11 23 23 456

Output:- [1, 11, 23, 23, 456]

i hope you find it useful